# Enter Previous Workday into Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I enter a formula to display the previous workday into the active cell using VBA. I've only found code that would cause today's date to appear in a message box.

So my code currently ends with:

```
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Inventory").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(20,4).Select
```

This pastes some data and then drops the active cell off exactly where I need it. At this point, I want to enter the previous workday, copy it, and paste it in all uninterrupted blank rows above it.

Comment: Isn't there a `WORKDAY` function that does exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1)
```

Note that you should generally avoid using `Select` - see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/) for more detail.